# Show two sets are isomorphic as fields

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

We have two sets $A$ and $B$. $A = \{a + b \sqrt{2}: a, b \in \mathbb{Z}_{5}\}$ and $B = \{ a + b \sqrt{3}: a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{5}\}$. We want to show that they are isomorphic as fields. I think that the structure of these two sets are a little bit similar ot $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ and $\mathbb{Q} [\sqrt{3}]$. However, $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is not isomorphic with $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$. Thus,I tried to use the definition of isomorphism. We need to find a bijection mapping $\phi$ from $A$ to $B$ such that $\phi(a + b) = \phi(a) + \phi(b)$, for all $a,b \in A$. And also we need $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$, for all $a,b \in A$. But I'm confused about how to find such a mapping. Could anyone help me this please? 
 Thanks so much!

Comment: Isomorphic as rings? as groups? as vector spaces?

Comment: What do you mean by $\sqrt 2$, say, here?  Are you looking at an extension field of $\mathbb Z_5$ in which $x^2-2$ is solvable?  If so, then $(2\sqrt 2)^2\equiv 4\times 2\equiv 3\pmod 5$.  Is that what you are after?

Comment: @jjagmath isomorphic as fields. I've edited both the title and the content. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @lulu it's just elements in the set need to be in the form of $a + b \sqrt{2}$

Comment: Right.  So take the field isomorphism given by setting $2 \sqrt 2 =\sqrt 3$.  Note that, over the rationals say, there's nothing like that equality.  You can't solve $\sqrt 2 =n+m\sqrt 3$ with $n,m\in \mathbb Q$.  That's the point here.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for your comment! I'll definitely try this!

Comment: in the same spirit, you should convince yourself that the field  $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q(m+n\sqrt 2)$ for $m,n\in \mathbb Q$ (with $n\neq 0$)

Comment: @lulu But then when I try to prove its closure under multiplication, I got $\phi(a + b\sqrt{2}) \cdot \phi(c + d\sqrt{2}) = (a + b\sqrt{3})\cdot (c + d\sqrt{3}) = (a + 2b\sqrt{2}) \cdot (c + 2d\sqrt{2}) = ac + (2\sqrt{2})^2 bd + (ad + bc)2\sqrt{2}$. Then $\phi((a + b\sqrt{2})\cdot (c + \sqrt{2})) = \phi(ac + 2bd + (ad + bc) \sqrt{2}) = ac+2bd + \sqrt{3}(ad + bc)\sqrt{2} = ac + 2bd + 2\sqrt{2}(ad +bc)\sqrt{2}$, which is not equal

Comment: I don't understand.  If you want to go from $A\to B$, then use $\sqrt 2=3\sqrt 3$.  We then have $a+b\sqrt 2=a+3b\sqrt 3$, so that tells you the isomorphism.  Of course it is compatible with multiplication since the field elements coincide.

Comment: Specifically, if we (somewhat abusively) denote by $(a,b)$ elements of both fields (so that $(a,b)$ denotes $a+b\sqrt 2$ in $A$ and it denotes $a+b\sqrt 3$ in $B$) then the isomorphism is $\phi: A\to B$, $\phi(a,b)=(a,3b)$.

Answer (score 1):

In the following we shall directly write $n$ when we mean $\bar{n}$ or  $n+5\mathbb{Z}$.

More formally the question can be restated as:

> Let $F_5$ be the field with $5$ elements. Then $F_5(a)\cong F_5(b)$,
> where ${\rm irr}(a, F_5)=x^2-2$ and ${\rm irr}(b, F_5)=x^2-3$.

Solution:

Method 1: Since $F_5(a)$, $F_5(b)$ both have dimension $2$ as vector space over $F_5$, they both have $25$ elements. Any two finite fields with same cardinality are isomorphic.

Method 2: For the second field, $b^2-3=0\implies (3b)^2-2=0$. Therefore ${\rm irr}(3b, F_5)=x^2-2$. You can check $F_5(b)=F_5(3b)$ and $3b\mapsto a$ induces an isomorphism $F_5(a)\cong F_5(b)$.