Let $\alpha, \beta \in \overline{\mathbb{Z}}_2$ be zeros of $x^3+x^2+1$, $x^3+x+1$. Show that $\mathbb{Z}_2(\alpha) = \mathbb{Z}_2(\beta)$.
This problem is from Fraleigh's Abstract Algebra, section 33, problem 9. According to Theorem 33.3, the elements of an extension $E$ (with $|E|=p^n$) of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ contained in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are exactly the roots of $x^{p^n}-x$. Moreover, according to Theorem 33.12, two finite fields with $p^n$ elements are isomorphic. However, I don't understand why equality holds in the problem instead of isomorphism. Even if
(1) the sets of the two fields are identical and
(2) the two fields are isomorphic,
doesn't that only imply the existence of an automorphism between the fields, not that the two fields are identical?

Hint: $x^8 - x = x (x - 1) (x^3 + x^2 + 1) (x^3 + x + 1)$.

@qwerti, I request you should mention that your $\mathbb{Z}_p$ denotes the finite field with $p$ elements, the usual notation is $\mathbb{F}_p$. This is because $\mathbb{Z}_p$ also denotes the ring of $p$-adic integers

Not totally the same, but very similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4763591

As for why they are same: They are contained in the same algebraic closure.

@qwerti I've improved my answer. If you find something wrong, let me know it.

As a brief hint for a different approach: if $x = y+1$ then $x^3 + x + 1 = y^3 + y^2 + 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[y]$.


Observe $2^3 = 8$ and $$ x^8 - x = x (x - 1) (x^3 + x^2 + 1) (x^3 + x + 1) . $$
Since $x^3 + x^2 + 1$ and $x^3 + x + 1$ are cubic polynomials and do not have any zero in $\mathbb{F}_2$, they are irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_2$.
Thus, $\mathbb{F}_2 ( \alpha ) = \mathbb{F}_2 [x] / \langle x^3 + x^2 + 1 \rangle$ and $\mathbb{F}_2 ( \beta) = \mathbb{F}_2 [x] / \langle x^3 + x + 1 \rangle$.
Since $\alpha^7 = 1$ and $7$ is a prime number, the subgroup $\langle \alpha \rangle$ of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_2 ( \alpha )^\times$ has order $7$.
Hence, the field $\mathbb{F}_2 ( \alpha )$ has at least $8$ elements.
Meanwhile, the field $ K := \{ x \in \overline{\mathbb{F}}_2 \mid x^8 - x = 0 \} $ has at most $8$ elements.
Noting that the ring homomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{F}_2 ( \alpha ) \to K$ defined by
\begin{align*}
\phi & : a \mapsto a & \mathrm{for} \quad a \in \mathbb{F}_2 \\
\phi & : \alpha \mapsto \alpha  & \\
\end{align*}
is injective, we know that $\mathbb{F}_2 ( \alpha )$ has exactly $8$ elements.
By applying Theorem 33.12, we obtain that $\mathbb{F}_2 ( \alpha ) \cong \mathbb{F}_8$ as fields.
Similarly, $\mathbb{F}_2 ( \beta) \cong \mathbb{F}_8$ as fields.
Therefore, $\mathbb{F}_2 ( \alpha ) \cong \mathbb{F}_2 ( \beta )$ as fields.


Indeed, $\mathbb{F}_8 = \mathbb{F}_2 \cup \{ \alpha \in \overline{\mathbb{F}}_2 \mid \alpha^3 + \alpha^2 + 1 = 0 \} \cup \{ \beta \in \overline{\mathbb{F}}_2 \mid \beta^3 + \beta + 1 = 0 \}$.
